# how apply contrast to half of the image using openCV

Tags: image-processing

contrast_img = cv2.addWeighted(img, 2.5, np.zeros(img.shape, img.dtype), 0, 0)

How to change contrast of half of the image,i'm using the above code ,what change I need to in my code to do so

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow, please refer to the guidelines for asking a question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Please elaborate on what you want to do and also post what you have tried so far.

Comment: @saga_blast *"half of the image"* which half? upper, lower, right. left??

Comment: *upper half of the image

Answer (score 0):

You could slice out the top half of the image and apply the contrast function to just that.

top_half = img[0:int(height/2), :, :];

I'm fairly certain that with python aliasing applying the contrast to "top_half" would change the original "img" as well, but if not you can always just overlay the top_half onto img with this:

img[0:int(height/2), :, :] = top_half;

Note: images in opencv are numpy arrays with shape [height, width, channels] (grayscale images or other single-channel representations might be missing the last dimension). I'm assuming here that you're working with an rgb (bgr in opencv) image.